# not able to checkout master after merge conflict on a branch

Tags: git, git-branch

I have some merge conflict on a branch, I am no more interested in this branch and want to delete it.

But when I perform a git checkout master I get message "error: you need to resolve your current index first", and "needs merge" in front of every file.

How can I delete this branch?

Comment: What does `git status` say about any ongoing operation? (Are you in the middle of a rebase, cherry-pick, or revert, for instance?)

Answer (score 0):

`git merge --abort` .

This will reset your branch to previous state .

Then you can checkout `master` branch and delete your branch.

Comment: git merge --abort
fatal: There is no merge to abort (MERGE_HEAD missing).